# Object Oriented programming: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'center'

Tags: python, oop

I am trying to use classes/Methods to wrap around my code which otherwise works fine without OOP language.
Confusion arise for me when I dont know how to define the attribute correctly. For example, to set `=None` or `=number` etc?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from shapely.geometry.polygon import LinearRing
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

class cycloid_generation():

def __init__(self, axes=None, blank=None, plnt1=None, plnt2=None, 
             plnt3=None, pin_radius=10, pin_circle_radius=120, 
             eccentricity=5, p_pin_circle_radius=60, no_of_pins=16,
             p_number_of_pins=15, contraction=1, 
             rolling_circle_line=None, rolling_circle=None):
    
    self.plnt1 = plnt1
    self.plnt2 = plnt2
    self.plnt3 = plnt3
    self.pin_radius = pin_radius
    self.pin_circle_radius = pin_circle_radius
    self.eccentricity = eccentricity
    self.p_pin_circle_radius = p_pin_circle_radius
    self.p_number_of_pins = p_number_of_pins
    self.no_of_pins = no_of_pins
    self.blank = blank
    self.contraction = contraction
    self.rolling_circle_line = rolling_circle_line
    self.rolling_circle = rolling_circle
    

def setup_plot(self, amount):
    fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=(8, 8))
    ax = plt.axes(xlim=(-amount, amount), ylim=(-amount, amount))
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.ion()
    plt.show()
    return ax

def plots(self):
 
    self.axes = self.setup_plot((self.pin_circle_radius+4*self.pin_radius))
    self.contraction = self.rolling_circle_radius - self.eccentricity
    self.cycloid_base = plt.Circle((0, 0), 
                                   self.cycloid_base_radius, fill=False,
                                   linestyle='--', lw=2)
    self.axes.add_patch(self.cycloid_base)
    self.rolling_circle = plt.Circle((0, 0), 
                                     self.rolling_circle_radius, 
                                     fill=False, lw=2)
    self.axes.add_patch(self.rolling_circle)
    self.rolling_circle_line = plt.Line2D((0, 1), (0, 0), lw=2, color='red')
    self.axes.add_line(self.rolling_circle_line)
    return

def prmtrs(self, pin_radius, pin_circle_radius,
                    p_pin_circle_radius, number_of_pins, p_number_of_pins):
    self.rolling_circle_radius = self.pin_circle_radius/self.no_of_pins
    self.reduction_ratio = self.no_of_pins + 1  # reduction ratio
    self.cycloid_base_radius = (self.reduction_ratio
                                *self.rolling_circle_radius)
    self.p_rolling_circle_radius = (self.p_pin_circle_radius
                                    /self.p_number_of_pins)
    self.p_reduction_ratio = self.p_number_of_pins - 1
    self.p_cycloid_base_radius = (self.p_reduction_ratio
                                  *self.p_rolling_circle_radius)
    return self.p_cycloid_base_radius


def geom(self):
    
    for angle in range(0, 360):
        # rotate rolling circle round the center of the cycloid
        self.x = ((self.cycloid_base_radius - self.rolling_circle_radius)
                  * np.cos(np.radians(angle)))
        self.y = ((self.cycloid_base_radius - self.rolling_circle_radius)
                  * np.sin(np.radians(angle)))
        self.rolling_circle.center = (self.x, self.y)
        self.point_x = (self.x +
                        (self.rolling_circle_radius - self.contraction)
                        *np.cos(np.radians(self.no_of_pins*-angle)))
        self.point_y = (self.y +
                        (self.rolling_circle_radius - self.contraction)
                        *np.sin(np.radians(self.no_of_pins*-angle)))
    
        self.rolling_circle_line.set_xdata((self.x, self.point_x))
        self.rolling_circle_line.set_ydata((self.y, self.point_y))
        self.epicycloid_points.append([self.point_x, self.point_y])
        self.epicycloid.set_xy(self.epicycloid_points) 
        return 
    
    
def polygons(self):
    # polygon to hold the main epicycloid
    self.epicycloid_points = []
    self.epicycloid = plt.Polygon(self.blank, fill=False, closed=False, 
                             color='red', lw=2)
    self.axes.add_patch(self.epicycloid)

    # polygon to hold the main planet1 epicycloid
    self.plnt1_epicycloid_points = []
    self.plnt1_epicycloid = plt.Polygon(self.blank, fill=False, 
                                        closed=False, color='red', lw=2)
    self.axes.add_patch(self.plnt1_epicycloid)

    # polygon to hold the main planet2 epicycloid
    self.plnt2_epicycloid_points = []
    self.plnt2_epicycloid = plt.Polygon(self.blank, fill=False, 
                                        closed=False, color='red', lw=2)
    self.axes.add_patch(self.plnt2_epicycloid)

    return

geom = cycloid_generation()
geom.prmtrs(10,120,60,16, 16)
geom.geom()
geom.polygons()
```

**Error**:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'center'
```

**Desired Output**
Plots of geometry

Comment: You call `self.rolling_circle.center` and initialise `self.rolling_circle` with `None` (as a default argument of `__init__`). You initialise `self.rolling_circle` only in `plots` method but never call it.

Comment: Probably, because you did not provide [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and it's not very clear what you are asking.

Comment: How would I call "self.rolling_circle"

Comment: You are calling it right. The problem is that you initialize it to None. You need to call `plots` before using `self.rolling_circle` because you initialize it properly in the `plots` method. If you don't understand it, you should read more about OOP in python

Answer (score 0):

Error occurs at this line `self.rolling_circle.center = (self.x, self.y)`
It telling you, your object rolling_circle is a None type and that's because you don't assign any other value to it.

When you declare self.rolling_circle in your constructor you assign it rolling_circle value which is None by default .

```
def __init__(self, ..., rolling_circle=None):
    self.rolling_circle = rolling_circle
```

You have to make a cycloid_generation object and give a proper value to the rolling_circle otherwise it will be None and raise you the same error. `geom = cycloid_generation(rolling_circle=something)`

Comment: If i call it via 'geom = cycloid_generation(rolling_circle=1)'  it returns ''int' object has no attribute 'center''